# get the value of any clicked td jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

im traying to get the value of any clicked td and show this in a alert() window with jquery or javascript. I was trayin alote of code around the internet "googling" but anyone can do this but anyways i going to posted here...

```js
$("table tbody").click(function() {
  alert($(this).find('td.value').text());
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tbody').find('tr').click(function() {
    alert("row find");
    alert('You clicked row ' + ($(this).index() + 1));
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('table tbody').click(function() {
    var i = $(this).index();
    alert('Has clickado sobre el elemento número: ' + i);
  });
});

$("table tbody").live('click', function() {
  if $(this).index() === 1) {
  alert('The third row was clicked'); // Yes the third as it's zero base index
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>miguel</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using?.... `live()` has been deprecated for years now ... and is gone from current versions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not attach the `click` event directly to the `td`? You also need to make sure you're including jQuery...

```js
$( "td" ).click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>Nombre</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>miguel</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `jQuery` library to start working with it. Then just bind a click event to your `td` and you should see the `alert` pop up.

```
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

// Your code comes here
```

Also next time if something does not work, the first thing that you are supposed to so id open the console and check if you see any errors and act upon them.

- Using `console.log` instead of `alert` should be the way to go as `alert` blocks the UI thread completely.

```js
$("td").click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>id</td>
      <td>Nombre</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>miguel</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In case you aren't sure what Sushanth is saying, use the Dev Tools in Google Chrome to see what's going on at the console.  From your web page, press F12 -- then click the console tab. Here there be errors.